# Pull records that meet three criteria from query in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, relational-division

Creating a query that will return only records that have entries in all three categories.  Records are identified by a chemical ID number that is unique, but we may have many entries for that chemical ID.  I only want the ones that have been tested for each one of three taxon groups.

So:

Chem ID Taxon

1111    insect

1111    mammal

1111    plant

1251    plant

1251    insect

8588    plant

8789    mammal

8789    plant

I'd want to only return chemical ID 1111.

I feel like this should be easy given that the information is all contained in a query already.  Too new to sql to find a smart solution just yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could group by the ChemID, and then filter it to only include ChemID's that have three [distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) categories when grouped (meaning, get a count of unique category values). The below query will show you any ChemID that is in atleast 3 categories.

```
SELECT [ChemID]
FROM #chemicals
GROUP BY [ChemID]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Taxon]) >= 3
```

Comment: Patrick, thanks.  Does Access support that syntax?  Having trouble with the last line.  My bad for not specifying that ahead of time.

Comment: Looks like it does: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/having-clause-HP001032238.aspx

Comment: No problem. If you want to post what your query looks like and what error message you are getting, I can try to help further.